# CSS JS Fixed position sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sidebar

I have 2 blocks - one with fixed position and the other next to it. I would like the fixed block to increase in length after clicking the button, and the second block to decrease in size and to click everything again to return it to its original state. Fixed block will be sidebar menu, permanently glued.

Everything should happen at 100% width.

How to do it, but the important thing is that the width of the fixed block and the latter should be specified in **pixels, not in percent**.

Is this to be done?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery(".btn").click(function() {
    var div1 = jQuery(".left");
    var div2 = jQuery(".right");

    if (div1.width() < 200) {
      div1.animate({
        width: "25%"
      }, {
        duration: 200,
        specialEasing: {
          width: "linear"
        }
      });

      div2.animate({
        width: "75%"
      }, {
        duration: 200,
        specialEasing: {
          width: "linear"
        }
      });
    } else {
      div1.animate({
        width: "5%"
      }, {
        duration: 200,
        specialEasing: {
          width: "linear"
        }
      });
      div2.animate({
        width: "95%"
      }, {
        duration: 200,
        specialEasing: {
          width: "linear"
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  background: pink;
  z-index: 5;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="button" value="click" class="btn">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="content"> abc </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you wanna define both elements with the width set to pixels, the total width of your container should not be 100%. The container should be the sum of the width in pixels of both of the elements at any time. If you wanna work with 100% width you have to use percentages for both of for atleast one of the 2 elements. You could set the expanded width of the fixed block to `width: 300px` and then use calc for the other block `width: calc(100% - 300px)`

Comment: Your code seems to doing exactly what you want: increase the width of `left` and decrease the width of `right` or vice versa depending on the state of click button. The only caveat you mentioned was adding the height and width in pixels. Check out this plunker where I used `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to get the viewport measurements: https://plnkr.co/edit/SdHgZezASQHwf58FDRii?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything should happen at 100% width.
>
> ... in pixels, not in percent.

Are you sure that it's not the opposite? It's way more better to try to make yor css based on `%` rather that `px` or `rem` (unless it's required to do it in `px`)

In any case, I fixed your code, but in `%`, from now on you can play with px if that's the requirement:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  jQuery(".btn").click(function() {

    var leftDiv = jQuery(".left");
    var rightDiv = jQuery(".right");

    console.log("leftDiv width: " + leftDiv.width() +
      " - " + "rightDiv width: " + rightDiv.width())
      
    var minWidthForRight = $('.container').width() - 300;
    var maxWidthForRight = $('.container').width() - 100;

    if (leftDiv.width() < 200) {


      leftDiv.animate({
        width: "300px",
        
      }, {
        duration: 200,
        specialEasing: {
          width: "linear"
        }
      });

      rightDiv.animate({
        width: minWidthForRight
      }, {
        duration: 200,
        specialEasing: {
          width: "linear"
        }
      });

    } else {

      leftDiv.animate({
        width: "100px"
      }, {
        duration: 200,
        specialEasing: {
          width: "linear"
        }
      });

      rightDiv.animate({
        width: maxWidthForRight
      }, {
        duration: 200,
        specialEasing: {
          width: "linear"
        }
      });

    }

  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  background: pink;
  z-index: 5;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="left">
    <input type="button" value="click" class="btn">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="content"> abc </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

EDIT

Yes, it is possible to keep the left side in px and the left side in %, not % itself but calculated in px based on screen resolution.

Basically you take the container width and "eliminate" the width that you specified in animation:

```
var minWidthForRight = $('.container').width() - 300;
```

The right side will be: `300 + (100% - 300 )` and same for left: `100 + (100% - 100 )`

Comment: Is possible to specify only the fixed element value in width and the second block to fill the rest with 100%?

Comment: Yes, i made an edit on code and some lil explanantion. xD